# HTML5 canvas won't allow me to move object inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a project which uses HTML5 and the jQuery fabric canvas library. I've added an image to the canvas using fabric but it does not allow me to move that image inside the canvas.

How can I get the image to move inside the canvas?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(
    '<?php echo $url; ?>uploads/canvas_uploads/Landscape_' + name, 
    function(image) {
        my_image  = image;
        my_image.top = -1;
        my_image.lockMovementY = true;
        my_image.lockMovementX = false;
        my_image.left = -20;
        my_image.width  = ObjWidth;
        my_image.height = ObjHeight;
        canvas.add(my_image);
    }
);
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link?

Comment: How are you trying to move the image? By mouse drag, click, automatically in code...?

Comment: on click function when i click on the image i call a jquery function and in that jquery i write the above code which add the image to canvas using the above code through url

Comment: when i inspect element my page then it allow me to move the image

Answer (score 0):

Try with `canvas.renderAll();` after `canvs.add(image);`

Regards.

Comment: my_image  = image;
     my_image.top = -1;
     my_image.lockMovementY = true;
     my_image.lockMovementX = false;
     my_image.left = -20;
     my_image.width  = ObjWidth;
     my_image.height = ObjHeight;
     canvas.add(my_image);
     canvas.renderAll();